# Retirar stopwords listadas em um arquivo txt de um outro arquivo txt

Tags: c, c++

Boa noite galera, preciso de ajuda. Estou fazendo pré-processamento de texto e para isso preciso remover de um livro em formato .txt todas as `stopwords` encontradas em um arquivo também de texto "stopwords_br.txt". Encontrei um programa creio eu que um pouco parecido com o que estou procurando. No entanto esta em C++ e eu não entendo os comandos.

Me ajudem se possível. Obrigada.

```
string line, deleteline;
ifstream stopword;
stopword.open("example.txt");
if (stopword.is_open())
{
    while ( getline (stopword,line) )
    {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    stopword.close();
}    
else cout << "Unable to open file";

ofstream temp;
temp.open("temp.txt");

cout << "Please input the stop-word you want to delete..\n ";
cin >> deleteline;

while (getline(stopword,line))
{
    if (line != deleteline)
    {
        temp << line << endl;
    }
}
temp.close();
stopword.close();
remove("example.txt");
rename("temp.txt","example.txt");
cout <<endl<<endl<<endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Como é formato do arquivo "stopwords_br.txt"?

O código abaixo, baseado no que você passou, lê as informações do arquivo e remove a palavra. Salva as informações em um novo arquivo e remove o anterior.

```
    int main()
{

    string line, stopword;
    ifstream text_file; 
    text_file.open("c:\temp\exemplo.txt");
```

`if(text_file.is_open()){
    while(getline(text_file, line)){
        cout << line << endl;
    }

    text_file.close();
}else cout << "Unable to open file";

cout << "\nPlease input the stop-word you want do delete." << endl;
cin >> stopword;

text_file.open("c:\\temp\\exemplo.txt");

ofstream temp;
temp.open("c:\\temp\\temp.txt");

if(text_file.is_open()){
    while(getline(text_file, line)){
        int achou = 1;

        while(achou > 0){
            int pos = line.find(stopword);
            if(pos >= 0){
                line.erase(pos, stopword.length());
            }else{
                achou = pos;
            }
        }

        temp << line << endl;
    }
}

temp.close();
text_file.close();
remove("c:\\temp\\exemplo.txt");
rename("c:\\temp\\temp.txt", "c:\\temp\\exemplo.txt");

cout << endl << endl<< endl;

system("pause");
return 0;`

Comment: A ideia geral é boa mas (1) só trata uma stopword; (2) por exemplo sendo "a" uma stopword, não iria remover todos os "a" de todas as palavras do texto?

Answer (score 0):

Se estivermos em ambiente Linux, e se pudermos usar Sed e Perl propunha...

```
sed -rf <(perl -00nE 'say "s/\\<(",join("|",split),")\\>//g"' stopw.txt) l.txt
```

Exemplo:

```
$ cat stopwords 
a
de
que
para
em
é

$ cat livro 
a minha tia de Braga é que em breve me vem visitar.

$ sed -rf <(perl -00nE 'say "s/\\<(",join("|",split),")\\>//g"' stopwords) livro 
 minha tia  Braga    breve me vem visitar.
```

em que:

- `perl -00nE 'say "s/\\<(",join("|",split),")\\>//g"' stopwords`, dá `s/\<(a|de|que|para|em|é)\>//g`, ou seja calcula uma substituição sed,
- que é seguidamente aplicado ao livro (`sed -rf prog livro`).